# What is a proper way of installing dependencies in Airflow?

Tags: docker-compose, airflow

I am trying to install git inside Airflow scheduler by `apt-get install -y git` (see docker-compose.yml below) and I get `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`.

Is this even a good direction here by installing this package in "command"?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  postgres:
    ...
  init:
    ...
  webserver:
    ...
  scheduler:
    image: *airflow_image
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh"]
    command: ["-c",
        "apt-get install -y git \
        && pip install -r /opt/airflow/tmp/requirements.txt \
        && airflow scheduler"]

volumes:
  logs:
```

Comment: You probably want to bake your own docker image with your dependencies and distribute it to an image repository. It saves on bandwidth and improves the startup time of your container.

Comment: Yup, true - but it's quite a cumbersome process while you're during development